# Flask Python App Fails to create database cursor

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to do a basic query in `flask`, and output it. In `prod` this is failing to create a `mysql` cursor.

**Here is `app.py`:**

```
#from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
import pymysql.cursors

connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='myusr', port=3306, password='mypass', db='mydb', charset='utf8mb4', cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)


@app.route('/', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def email():


    form = EmailForm()

    try:
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute("SELECT post_title, post_name, YEAR(post_date) YEAR, MONTH(post_date) MONTH FROM mydb.wp_posts WHERE post_status='publish' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3")
            r = cursor.fetchall()
            print(r)
    Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        connection.close()
```

My `db gui` program has these access rights for my database user (see black lines):
[image: img]

**UPDATED::: Error received, when i include the above `try` line:**

```
2017/01/02 09:10:30 [error] 1042#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: xx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: mysite.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8001/", host: "mysite.com"
```

I tested this import(`from flask_mysqldb import MySQL`) is working fine in the interpreter, `mysql` itself is also installed.

I tested that the credentials above work to connect via a `gui db program`

What am I doing wrong? I was following the [official documentation](http://flask-mysqldb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for flask and mysql , but now im following [link2](https://github.com/metmirr/pythonkonusuyor/blob/master/mysql_connect.py)

Why is this failing? Anyone see anything?

Thank you

Comment: Please provide the error message you receive.

Comment: When i include the `cursor` above, nginx fails with Http 502 Error

Comment: @PavelRyvintsev - please see updated error, and db permissions.

Comment: Nginx shadows the real error you get. Maybe if you will run the flask app directly, you will get more meaningful error message.

Comment: @PavelRyvintsev - it means there is an error running `app.py` - im asking if my mysqldb above looks good. Also `how can i a run the flask app directly?

Comment: Have you tried pure python mysql connection? It looks like permissions issue

Comment: @metmirr - can you provide an example please?

Comment: According to flask_mysqldb documentation write the code related to DB in one of the route functions and not in "main" as you have done in your example: http://flask-mysqldb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: @PavelRyvintsev - this results in an "Internal Server Error" error. See updated code

Comment: first: you could run it with debug mode ie. `app.debug = True` and maybe you see more information when you open page in browser. second: normally `nginx` runs as user `wwwdata` which has different privillages and maybe it connects to database as `wwwdata`.

Comment: @furas - thanks for your comment. I'm running with `debug=True`. How can i check these permissions? I have other sites running on the same server, that don't have any issue connecting to the same db (running as the same user)

Comment: try this https://github.com/metmirr/pythonkonusuyor/blob/master/mysql_connect.py and tell us the result?

Comment: btw: you could try to use `try/catch` to get some information about error

Comment: @furas please see updated with this code

Comment: `catch Exception as e: print(e)` could be more usefull - it should give some information about error.

Comment: Edited code with except. Either way it fails resulting in `502 bad gateway` from nginx, if i just run `python app.py` it says  `Syntax error: invalid syntax` at `Exception as e:`

Answer (score 0):

Please try changing your code the following way and running the file directly

```
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_PORT'] = '3306'
app.config['MYSQL_DB']   = 'mydb'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'myuser'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = 'mypass'
mysql = MySQL(app)

@app.route('/')
def test():
   cur = mysql.connection.cursor()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run()
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I tried this, and it results in an `500 internal server error`

Comment: @Jshee Internal Server Error could be anything. If you will run the code above directly and not via Nginx, you will be able to see the the error message. Just run it as you would run any other python file.

Comment: when i run it like this i get:  `python app.py` I get :  `* Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger pin code: 115-763-111`  thoughts?